# Recommendable Node.JS provider?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, captcha

I looking for a provider, where I can host my Node.js web site(s). I know there are a lot, but I would like to know which you can recommend, I would like to have the possebility to install packages like Handlebars,express, capchas and so on and they should always use the lastest node.js?

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely recommend [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/), it is free to use for small apps, and has everything you need as modules. Never had a problem, and the documentation is awesome. It has a neat interface too.

Comment: can i install handlebars.js for free for the non commcercial cversion , if so how ?